# Get VLC to Automatically Set Screen Resolution in Full Screen

Tags: video, resolution, vlc-media-player

My normal screen resolution is 1080 pixels tall. DVD content ranges, but I'm currently watching a 480-pixels-tall movie. When playing VLC in full screen, it scales the media to match the 1080-tall screen. To anticipate this, I change the screen resolution to 480 tall before watching the movie, then put it in full screen, and it looks great: crisper video, no aliasing, etc.

Is there a way to get VLC to put the screen mode to the media's resolution when in full screen? If not, is there another free software video player that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a list of [VLC command-line options](https://www.videolan.org/doc/vlc-user-guide/en/ch04.html), including *--width, --height*  to set the video window dimensions. However, other players, such as [Media Player Classic - Home Cinema](https://mpc-hc.org/), offer options such as scaling to a multiple of the video's actual resolution, which reduces aliasing.

Comment: I do need it to run in full screen. I just want full screen to be the appropriate resolution. I want the screen to change video modes. I want the screen to change resolutions to the desired resolution. Hopefully I'm being clear? :-)

Comment: Ah! As far as I know, there is no option to change screen resolution based on video res, and for good reason: a video might have such low resolution as to make the screen unusable after playing it, or settings that might not even be playable on your video setup. E.G., what if your viewing a 4k video and the output device cannot display it? Screen resolution is *not* to be trifled with.